# How to make my angular 4 code compatible with firefox?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tested my angular 4 code in chrome browser but now when I open it in firefox, it is giving the below error

```
ERROR TypeError: hostEl.createShadowRoot is not a function
Stack trace:
ShadowDomRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:166030:28
../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js/DomRendererFactory2.prototype.createRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:165743:24
../../../platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js/AnimationRendererFactory.prototype.createRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:167745:41
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</DebugRendererFactory2.prototype.createRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:127912:35
createComponentView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:126511:24
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:127880:39
debugCreateComponentView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:127237:12
createViewNodes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:126569:37
createRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:126494:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:127880:39
debugCreateRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:127197:12
```

I have used ViewEncapsulation.Native in my code but I am not able to remove this ViewEncapsulation.Native. The other solution I have got is to use polyfills to avoid this error, but my index.html file (generated in dist folder) already have polyfills file.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using (ViewEncapsulation.Native) encapsulation native shadow DOM, you have to know that it is available only in chrome, use emulated or you can integrate this https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/  for web component compatibility with other browsers, i don't think that you have other options
you can use the polyfills that way :

```
  npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs
```

and you can use the webcomponents-sd-ce to custom elements and shadow DOM:
add it to your polyfills.ts

```
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-sd-ce.js';
```

Comment: thank you, Do you know how to use it in typescript or angular 4 using npm

Comment: @Fateh, Getting error as =>  ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-sd-ce.js'

Comment: Is there any file like webcomponents-sd-ce.js?

Comment: the import statement is like below on newer versions
`import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce';`
btw solution doest work, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcomponent-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked is from the link

```
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6531
```

i.e. remove ViewEncapsulation.None or ViewEncapsulation.Native from all the typescript files.

And add any css files to the index.html file.

The other solutions using polyfills did not resolve the issue and started getting the same error from jquery-2.1.3.min.js file.