# Angular4 ViewEncapsulation.Native in Firefox using @webcomponents

Tags: angular, web-component

According to the accepted solution on [How to make my angular 4 code compatible with firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211542/how-to-make-my-angular-4-code-compatible-with-firefox), I should be able to use @webcomponents like so:

```
npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs
```

and by adding the following to my polyfills.ts:

```
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-sd-ce.js';
```

But I am still unable to use ViewEncapsulation.Native in Firefox in my Angular4 app.  Help?

Comment: I am facing same issue on ng 6 and ng 7, did you find a solution?

Comment: Which Firefox version are you using?